# Listing choices in optparse help output

Tags: python

When you generate help for an option with Python's optparse module, you can use the `%defualt` placeholder to insert the default value for the option into the help. It there anyway of doing the same thing for the valid choices when the type is choice?

E.g something like:

```
import optparse
parser=optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-m","--method",
                  type = "choice", choices = ("method1","method2","method3"),
                  help = "Method to use. Valid choices are %choices. Default: %default")
```

Comment: Optparse is considered to be deprecated. You should use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html).

Comment: @msvalkon: do you have a solution for this using argparse?

Comment: @JohnZwinck There we go, added one after all.

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm working within a framework that uses optparse and don't have the option to switch to using argparse until upstream does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your problem is that you don't want to repeat the list of choices.  Fortunately variables are universal if sometimes ugly solution to this kind of problem.  So the ugly-but-pragmatic answer is:

```
import optparse

choices_m = ("method1","method2","method3")
default_m = "method_1"

parser=optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-m","--method",
                  type = "choice", choices = choices_m, 
                  default = defult_m,
                  help = "Method to use. Valid choices are %s. Default: %s"\
                         % (choices_m, default_m)
```

And of course this kind of thing can be done using argparse too.

Comment: The problem is to ensure that any future changes to the list of valid options is automatically reflected in the help message. This should work as long as a future maintainer twigs as to what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

As @msvalkon commented, `optparse` is deprecated - use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead.

You can specify `%(choices)s` placeholder in the `help` argument:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-m",
                    "--method",
                    type=str,
                    choices=("method1", "method2", "method3"),
                    help = "Method to use. Valid choices are %(choices)s. Default: %(default)s",
                    default="method1")

parser.parse_args()
```

Here's what on the console:

```
$ python test.py --help
usage: test.py [-h] [-m {method1,method2,method3}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m {method1,method2,method3}, --method {method1,method2,method3}
                        Method to use. Valid choices are method1, method2,
                        method3. Default: method1
```

Comment: Maybe add the `default='method_n'`?

Answer (score 1):

[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html) prints the choices by default, as you can see in the demo below. One way to print the defaults automatically is to use the [`ArgumentsDefaultHelpFormatter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter).

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-m","--method", type=str, choices=("method1","method2","method3"),
              default="method1", help = "Method to use.")

parser.parse_args()
```

DEMO:

```
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-m {method1,method2,method3}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m {method1,method2,method3}, --method {method1,method2,method3}
                        Method to use. (default: method1)
```